# `udevd command not found` - I just can't get a command list to work

Tags: package-management, udev

I have the following command execution order to test something with docker. The problem is that `udevd` is not a binary that I can execute where the command `udevd --debug &` becomes useless or better said is just not working.

```
I have this script (command list):
$ docker run -it --privileged debian /bin/bash
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install xserver-xorg xorg jwm
$ udevd --debug &
$ udevadm trigger
<lots of output, brace yourself>
$ startx
```

When executing this I have this happening:

```
root@ba9551bd941f:/# udevd --debug &
[1] 9688
root@ba9551bd941f:/# bash: udevd: command not found
udevadm trigger
[1]+  Exit 127                udevd --debug
root@ba9551bd941f:/#
```

I also have no idea how to install `udevd` or whatever makes it appear. The interwebz is only talking about `udev` being not a binary (not mentioning `udevd`) and that it's always inside some base packages.

I found this here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/udevd
Which tells me it's a binary - but where to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current version of Debian (10), `udevd` is now [`systemd-udevd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-udevd.html), and it’s not on the default path; you need to run

```
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --debug &
```

instead.